# Column generation based on 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df1 which has :

```
F_Id    I_Code  F_Date
FT-56832    2   01/09/2019
FT-93828    1   01/09/2019
FT-13853    2   02/09/2019
FT-18858    3   02/09/2019
FT-19010    2   03/09/2019
FT-62064    5   02/09/2019
FT-94494    4   03/09/2019
FT-73594    2   03/09/2019
FT-78590    3   01/09/2019
FT-14296    4   01/09/2019
FT-82529    3   03/09/2019
FT-33266    3   04/09/2019
FT-58456    4   02/09/2019
FT-16693    4   04/09/2019
FT-69073    4   02/09/2019
FT-69649    1   05/09/2019
```

for each (I_code,F_Date) there are 5 different ID's associated with it.

I have another dataframe df2 that has following columns :

```
F_Date  num_i_found
01/09/2019  5
01/09/2019  3
02/09/2019  5
02/09/2019  5
03/09/2019  3
02/09/2019  4
03/09/2019  4
03/09/2019  5
01/09/2019  5
01/09/2019  4
03/09/2019  3
04/09/2019  5
02/09/2019  4
04/09/2019  5
02/09/2019  4
05/09/2019  4
```

I want to generate a new column ID_found in df2 such that its an array with ID's.

for example,for 1/09/2019 num_i_found is 4, then ID_found will be the 4 ID's out of 5 from the df1. (FT-56832,FT-93828, F-78590, ...).

is there a pandas way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary of lists and filter by indexing by `num_i_found` values:

**Notice**: If values is not match like for first rows it mens in sample data are only `4` values for `01/09/2019`, I guess in real data is all 5 values in `d` for each datetime, so working like you need.

```
d = df1.groupby('F_Date')['F_Id'].apply(list).to_dict()

print (d)
{'01/09/2019': ['FT-56832', 'FT-93828', 'FT-78590', 'FT-14296'],
 '02/09/2019': ['FT-13853', 'FT-18858', 'FT-62064', 'FT-58456', 'FT-69073'],
 '03/09/2019': ['FT-19010', 'FT-94494', 'FT-73594', 'FT-82529'], 
 '04/09/2019': ['FT-33266', 'FT-16693'], 
 '05/09/2019': ['FT-69649']}
```

---

```
df2['new'] = df2.apply(lambda x: d.get(x['F_Date'], [])[:x['num_i_found']], axis=1)
print (df2)
        F_Date  num_i_found                                                new
0   01/09/2019            5           [FT-56832, FT-93828, FT-78590, FT-14296]
1   01/09/2019            3                     [FT-56832, FT-93828, FT-78590]
2   02/09/2019            5  [FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456, FT-69...
3   02/09/2019            5  [FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456, FT-69...
4   03/09/2019            3                     [FT-19010, FT-94494, FT-73594]
5   02/09/2019            4           [FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456]
6   03/09/2019            4           [FT-19010, FT-94494, FT-73594, FT-82529]
7   03/09/2019            5           [FT-19010, FT-94494, FT-73594, FT-82529]
8   01/09/2019            5           [FT-56832, FT-93828, FT-78590, FT-14296]
9   01/09/2019            4           [FT-56832, FT-93828, FT-78590, FT-14296]
10  03/09/2019            3                     [FT-19010, FT-94494, FT-73594]
11  04/09/2019            5                               [FT-33266, FT-16693]
12  02/09/2019            4           [FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456]
13  04/09/2019            5                               [FT-33266, FT-16693]
14  02/09/2019            4           [FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456]
15  05/09/2019            4                                         [FT-69649]
```

If need strings:

```
d = df1.groupby('F_Date')['F_Id'].apply(list).to_dict()

df2['new'] = df2.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(d.get(x['F_Date'], [])[:x['num_i_found']]), axis=1)
print (df2)
        F_Date  num_i_found                                               new
0   01/09/2019            5            FT-56832, FT-93828, FT-78590, FT-14296
1   01/09/2019            3                      FT-56832, FT-93828, FT-78590
2   02/09/2019            5  FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456, FT-69073
3   02/09/2019            5  FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456, FT-69073
4   03/09/2019            3                      FT-19010, FT-94494, FT-73594
5   02/09/2019            4            FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456
6   03/09/2019            4            FT-19010, FT-94494, FT-73594, FT-82529
7   03/09/2019            5            FT-19010, FT-94494, FT-73594, FT-82529
8   01/09/2019            5            FT-56832, FT-93828, FT-78590, FT-14296
9   01/09/2019            4            FT-56832, FT-93828, FT-78590, FT-14296
10  03/09/2019            3                      FT-19010, FT-94494, FT-73594
11  04/09/2019            5                                FT-33266, FT-16693
12  02/09/2019            4            FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456
13  04/09/2019            5                                FT-33266, FT-16693
14  02/09/2019            4            FT-13853, FT-18858, FT-62064, FT-58456
15  05/09/2019            4                                          FT-69649
```

Comment: I wanted to get new column in the df2. i.e. F_date, num_i_found, new

Comment: If num_i_found is 5, then pick all ID's from df1 and append in array and add to a new column

Comment: @user3759616 - oops, I assign to df1 instead `df2`, not is ti correct.

Comment: like for the first entry i.e. 01/09/2019 there are 4 entries in df1 as of data shared, but in reality there are 5, would this pick 5 and then assign to column 'new'

Comment: @user3759616 - Just added notice ;)